# Elasticsearch querying a multi-valued field with position (index)

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document with multiple multi-valued fields.
I want to search for documents that have a certain value, on a certain field, in a given position.

For example, I have this document :

```
 {
    "color": [ "red", "blue" ]
 }
```

How do I write a query to get documents that have the value "Red", in position 0 for field color ?

Comment: What is the purpose of this? I ask because the way is using [scripts](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-using.html) but this will bring performance drop in the search.

Comment: It's a use case needed on an app.
Basically we index data, some might be a string, date or an array of strings.
And I need to do a search on certain values based on their position in an array